# ESP32-s3 web server setup with GPRS connection to receive HTTP requests

Tags: arduino, webserver, esp32, gsm

I want to send http request to my esp32-s3 which uses gsm shield to connect to net. Basically, I want to send a command to enable or disable one of esp output. Something like this I want to send:

```
{
    "ID": "123456789",
    "action": "on"
}
```

What I did, first I tried to only connect with gsm to net, what was working.

```
#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_M95
#include <TinyGsmClient.h>
#include <AsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const char apn[] = "internet";
const char gprsUser[] = "";
const char gprsPass[] = "";

SoftwareSerial SerialAT(38, 39);
TinyGsm modem(SerialAT);
AsyncWebServer server(8888);

void setup()
{
    delay(15000);
    Serial.begin(115200);

    // Set GSM module baud rate
    SerialAT.begin(9600);

    // Wait for GSM module to initialize
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Initializing GSM module...");
    modem.init();
    String modemInfo = modem.getModemInfo();
    Serial.print("Modem: ");
    Serial.println(modemInfo);

    // Connect to the internet using GPRS
    Serial.println("Connecting to GPRS...");
    if (!modem.gprsConnect(apn, gprsUser, gprsPass))
    {
        Serial.println("Failed to connect to GPRS");
        while (true)
            ;
    }

    Serial.println("Connected to GPRS");
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println(modem.getLocalIP());
    delay(1000);
    // Start the web server
    server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request)
              { request->send(200, "text/plain", "Hello, World!"); });

    server.on("/data", HTTP_POST, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request)
              {
    if (request->hasParam("key1") && request->hasParam("key2")) {
      String key1 = request->getParam("key1")->value();
      String key2 = request->getParam("key2")->value();
      
      // Process the data as needed
      
      request->send(200, "text/plain", "Data received");
    } else {
      request->send(400, "text/plain", "Bad request");
    } });
    Serial.println(modem.isGprsConnected());
    delay(1000);
    server.begin();
}

void loop()
{
    // Handle other tasks, if any
}
```

This is code I used. Problem is, that when it comes to executing server.begin() line, esp "crashes". On my PC I can hear sound of unplugged USB and in VScode I need to reconnect to serial. After that same thing keep hapening. Anyone have idea what might cause this problem. When it comes to using WiFi (connect with WiFi and start webserver), everything works fine. Thanks for any help.

I wonder if it is even possible to do that. I didnt found any examples where someone tried to start web server like this, everywhere was only examples with sending data through gsm with http requests.

Comment: Your GPRS module has a maximum data rate of 85.6kbps, if you really need a server, find the right technology. And there is no AT Command set for supporting server functionality.

Comment: @hcheung There's nothing wrong with GPRS and 85.6kbps if you don't need more bandwidth or sub-100ms latency. For a few light-weight HTTP commands per second it's more then enough. Granted, 2G has already been or will be sunset in many regions of the world. There's also no need for AT commands with TCP/IP support - he has a TCP/IP stack and a dialup client.

Comment: Hi, I tried to use your code. When i paste the public ip and tried to send url to the public ip with the specific port, it can׳t be reached. Do i need to add some code of wifi Config or another solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

GSM modules are notoriously power hungry (depends on the details, but especially when starting up and registering with the network). Your computer's USB port probably doesn't supply enough current (it's only required to supply 500mA at 5V by the USB spec).

I would try to supply independent power to the GSM module if it accepts it, usually something capable of 5V@2A is a good place to start. You can also try an external USB hub with its own power supply (again, 2A minimum), if you're lucky then some allow a single port to draw most of the current.